# Updating multiple records from a saved search results

Tags: netsuite

I have a script (below) that does the following:

- Gets the Sales Order id for the current record
- Gets the created from    id for the current record
- Loads a saved search that searches through all entries in a custom
  record
- Uses the created from id as a filter for the saved search
- Updates a field in the custom record that is found

All works well except I am running into a road block when more than 1 record is found.

How can I update multiple records?

Any tips or hints on how i can achieve this?

Code:

```
/**
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType ClientScript
      * @NModuleScope SameAccount
     */
    define(['N/record', 'N/search'], 
    function (record, currentRecord, search) {
        function afterSubmit(context) {
    var currentRecord = context.newRecord;
    var createdFrom = currentRecord.getValue({"fieldId": "createdfrom"});
    var salesOrderId = currentRecord.getValue({"fieldId": "id"});
    var mySearch = search.load({
         id: 'customsearch1086'
        });
    var filter1 = search.createFilter({
    name: 'custrecord_estimate_id',
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: createdFrom
    });
    mySearch.filters.push(filter1);
    var result = mySearch.run().getRange(0, 1000);
    var ids = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
    ids.push(result[i].getValue({ name: 'id'}));
    }
    var gdid = parseInt(ids);
    if (gdid) {
    var myRecord = record.load({
    type: 'customrecord352', 
    id: gdid,
    isDynamic: true
    });
        record.submitFields({
            "type": 'customrecord352',
            "id": gdid,
            "values": {
            "custrecord_salesOrder_id": salesOrderId
            }
        });
    }
    else {
    // Do Nothing
    }

            return {
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move record.submitFields inside the loop that iterates through the search results. Please be aware of the governance usage limits as well. You don't need the record.load call - please remove it.